# Has Stack Overflow's font been changed?

Tags: discussion, design

Was there any change applied to the Stack Overflow website design including changing its web font recently?

I'm using Firefox 65 64-bit on Ubuntu 18.04 (Kubuntu), and I visit the website daily and I noticed some difference in the font and I want to be sure of whether there was a change or not.

Comment: It looks exactly the same as yesterday for me: Comic sans all around, bright purple backround and unicorns everywhere.

Comment: @yivi Wow I'm jealous - mine's just this boring Arial font and white background...

Comment: And I'm struck here with Wingdings...

Comment: I have Firefox Nightly 67.0a1. Looks the same as ever. Do you have the option “Allow sites to use custom fonts instead of the ones above” (or similar) in your font settings enabled?

Comment: What's your last reference point for "different?" To my knowledge, nothing changed, but we could have recently broken some user scripts you might still be using which could cause it.

Comment: @yivi I wish I could favorite a comment hahaha

Comment: I got the feeling that the font rendering changed slightly when I updated to Firefox 65

Comment: I noticed this today in Chrome (actually Brave) on Windows 10. Subtle, but distinctly different. No change on iPhone or Chrome on Mac.

Comment: Chrome, windows 10. Arial and Consolas (for code). The font style is *Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;* and *Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, "Lucida Console", "Liberation Mono", "DejaVu Sans Mono", "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", "Courier New", monospace, sans-serif;*. Maybe you're getting one of the substitutes? Did you deep-six Arial?

Comment: Okay, I'm going to try to find out what's going on before we start speculating on supernatural causes. Will post back as soon as I find something.